# aggregate by ID and find min() and max() of time

Tags: r, aggregate, plyr

I got a transaction database which looks like this:

```
   AccountID PaymentDate PaymentAmount 
8         13  2020-02-09          1.00 
9         13  2020-01-25          4.20   
10        14  2020-01-01         30.68 
11        14  2020-02-01         30.68
```

PaymentDate is in posix format. With transaction data I don't want to aggregate by time intervals (this is well documented), but by ID.

Using min() with Posix times gives the first day, max() the last day. This is the information I need for every ID.

Ok, here is what I tried:

```
# 1.
summaryBy(PaymentDate ~ AccountID, data1, FUN=c(min) )
Fehler in tapply(lh.data[, lh.var[vv]], rh.string.factor, function(x) { : arguments must have same length

# 2.
ddply( data1, "AccountID", summarise, min(PaymentDate))
# returns 0 and warnings:
50: In output[[var]][rng] <- df[[var]] : Anzahl der zu ersetzenden Elemente ist kein Vielfaches der Ersetzungslänge

# 3.
aggregate(PaymentDate ~ AccountID, data1, min)
Fehler in model.frame.default(formula = PaymentDate ~ AccountID, data = data1) : ungültiger Typ (list) für die Variable 'PaymentDate'
```

Apparently, aggregate does not work with posix time if you need aggregates of time rather than aggregates by time.

But getting first and last transaction date must be possible?!

## Reply

Ok, since I cannot answer my own question yet, I post it here:

Interesting. Thank you!

I typically use the as.is=T option with read.csv, then convert time using strptime. So when I look at the structure of my data I get:

```
$ PaymentDate    : POSIXlt, format: "2020-02-04" "2020-02-04" "2020-02-04" ...
```

To me, that does not look like a factor. I can use min() and max() on the whole column and it works. Apparently, POSIXlt is more troublesome than I thought. Coming from the POSIXlt, I did

```
data$PaymentDate=as.Date(data$PaymentDate)
```

Looking at the structure, the Class is correctly set as Date.

```
$ PaymentDate    :Class 'Date'  num [1:10000] 18296 18296 18296 18297 18297 ...
```

Now it appears to work. However, only *ddply* return the right format "2020-01-25", while both *aggregate* and *summaryBy* return in the "18286" format. Was that days since 1970-01-01? Well, I guess I can convert it back.

```
foo=aggregate(PaymentDate ~ AccountID, data1, min)
as.Date(foo$PaymentDate,origin="1970-01-01")
```

However, there has to be some explanation. Also, ddply is much slower.

Oh, why do I use strptime first? Well, the date in the original file is in a different format, "%d-%m-%y". Using as.Date directly on this did not appear to work.

## EDIT

**dput of my data**

```
structure(list(AccountID = c(17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 
359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 
359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 365L, 939L, 939L, 939L, 997L, 997L, 1181L
), PaymentDate = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    mday = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 25L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 17L, 8L, 17L, 28L, 8L, 22L, 3L), 
    mon = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 
    7L, 10L, 10L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 11L, 11L, 4L, 10L), 
    year = c(110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
    110L, 109L, 110L, 110L, 109L, 110L, 110L, 109L, 110L, 109L, 
    109L, 110L, 109L, 110L, 109L, 110L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 110L, 
    109L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 109L, 109L, 110L, 109L, 109L, 110L, 
    109L, 109L), wday = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 
    4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 
    2L), yday = c(34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 39L, 24L, 
    0L, 31L, 59L, 90L, 90L, 151L, 181L, 181L, 212L, 243L, 243L, 
    273L, 273L, 334L, 334L, 32L, 60L, 152L, 213L, 305L, 305L, 
    122L, 3L, 123L, 197L, 97L, 75L, 361L, 341L, 141L, 306L), 
    isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("sec", 
"min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"
), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT")), .Names = c("AccountID", 
"PaymentDate"), row.names = c(NA, 40L), class = "data.frame")
```

**dput after doing as you suggested:**

```
structure(list(AccountID = c(359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 
359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 
359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 365L, 939L, 939L, 939L, 
997L, 997L, 1181L, 1181L, 1181L, 1181L, 1181L, 1181L, 1181L, 
1181L, 1181L, 1181L), PaymentDate = structure(c(14245, 14277, 
14305, 14335, 14368, 14397, 14426, 14457, 14488, 14518, 14550, 
14579, 14613, 14641, 14669, 14700, 14732, 14761, 14791, 14823, 
14853, 14883, 14915, 14944, 14442, 14320, 14606, 14707, 14386, 
14951, 14293, 14432, 14477, 14540, 14540, 14540, 14540, 14540, 
14540, 14551), class = "Date")), .Names = c("AccountID", "PaymentDate"
), row.names = c(10L, 25L, 26L, 13L, 33L, 27L, 16L, 18L, 19L, 
21L, 29L, 23L, 32L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 31L, 15L, 17L, 28L, 20L, 22L, 
30L, 24L, 34L, 36L, 37L, 35L, 39L, 38L, 45L, 42L, 48L, 50L, 51L, 
52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 40L), class = "data.frame")
```

**dput of raw data**

```
structure(list(AccountID = c(17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 
359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 
359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 365L, 939L, 939L, 939L, 997L, 997L, 1181L
), PaymentDate = c("04-02-2010", "04-02-2010", "04-02-2010", 
"05-02-2010", "05-02-2010", "05-02-2010", "05-02-2010", "09-02-2010", 
"25-01-2010", "01-01-2009", "01-02-2010", "01-03-2010", "01-04-2009", 
"01-04-2010", "01-06-2010", "01-07-2009", "01-07-2010", "01-08-2009", 
"01-09-2009", "01-09-2010", "01-10-2009", "01-10-2010", "01-12-2009", 
"01-12-2010", "02-02-2009", "02-03-2009", "02-06-2009", "02-08-2010", 
"02-11-2009", "02-11-2010", "03-05-2010", "04-01-2010", "04-05-2009", 
"17-07-2009", "08-04-2010", "17-03-2009", "28-12-2009", "08-12-2010", 
"22-05-2009", "03-11-2009")), .Names = c("AccountID", "PaymentDate"
), row.names = c(NA, 40L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I have edited your question to make it more readable.  When you paste code samples, use the `{}` curly brackets in the editor window to mark your code samples.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your data, and in particular the PaymentDate column, is a factor.  Both your `ddply` and `aggregate` solutions will work as written if you first transform the PaymentDate column:

```
#Recreate data and use dput() to replicate
df <- structure(list(AccountID = c(13L, 13L, 14L, 14L), PaymentDate = c("2020-02-09", 
            "2020-01-25", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01"), PaymentAmount = c(1, 
            4.2, 30.68, 30.68)), .Names = c("AccountID", "PaymentDate", "PaymentAmount"
    ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("8", "9", "10", "11"))
```

Change variable class to Date.

```
df$PaymentDate <- as.Date(df$PaymentDate)
```

Then run your original code.  Using ddply:

```
ddply(df, .(AccountID), summarize, data=min(PaymentDate))
  AccountID       data
1        13 2020-01-25
2        14 2020-01-01
```

Using aggregate:

```
aggregate(PaymentDate ~ AccountID, df, min)
  AccountID PaymentDate
1        13  2020-01-25
2        14  2020-01-01
```

There is another, more general way to avoid this problem.  By default, when you create a data.frame by using `read.table` (or its variants like `read.csv`) the parameter `stringsAsFactors` is set to `TRUE`.  When I recreate your data using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, you don't need the intermediate step of transforming PaymentDate, and your code works as written:

```
dat <- "   AccountID PaymentDate PaymentAmount 
8         13  2020-02-09          1.00 
9         13  2020-01-25          4.20   
10        14  2020-01-01         30.68 
11        14  2020-02-01         30.68 "

df <- read.table(textConnection(dat), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df

ddply(df, .(AccountID), summarize, data=min(PaymentDate))
  AccountID       data
1        13 2020-01-25
2        14 2020-01-01
```

Comment: @joint_p We won't know without know what your data is.  Can you use `dput()` on a sample of data and post the results in your question?